# No sound from applications on Ubuntu 14.04 (OS does make sound)

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Up until a few days ago sound was working fine on all applications.

Now, sound does not play from any application that I run, although OS sounds such as when I log in, and close a window, do play.

I also have Windows 10 loaded onto this laptop, and all sounds work correctly on there.

This leads me to the conclusion that it is an issue with Ubuntu.

The one thing that has been different since this has happened is that I plugged my laptop into a projector via HDMI and a soundbar via 3.5mm audio to play a movie. Sound has not played on applications since then. One might think it blew my speakers, yet sounds work perfect on Windows and also for operating system.

Any advice?

I've tried the solution that is posted on other answers here to no avail:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio unity-control-center
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Comment: Use the command `alsamixer` and make sure none of the channels are muted (mm instead of 00 is displayed). Annoyingly, these channels often mute themselves when connecting and disconnecting hardware. It is also recommended you disable automute although auto muting will still occur.

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Comment: @guntbert I remember fixing it but do not remember the solution. But I do remember finding it on this same site. So perhaps look at related questions

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by removing the pulseaudio cache and restarting pulseaudio.

> rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k